# anchor adds extra padding to image when in table

Tags: html, css

I have a table, and an anchor inside one of the td's, and an image inside of the anchor tag. Without applying display: inline-block to the anchor tag, I found that the image would extend above the anchor tag vertically (see 1st plunker). However, when I added display: inline-block, the anchor tag gains an additional bottom padding (see 2nd plunker). The height of the anchor tag is 18px, but that of the image is only 14px. Can anyone explain a) the logic behind the first plunker and b) where the space is coming from on the second plunker?

1st plunker (image extends beyond anchor) -> https://plnkr.co/edit/0OM9COpEYX5k98HK5ZvX?p=preview

```
<table>

  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <a>Random text</a>
        <a><img src="http://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery/1.jpg"></a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

2nd plunker (extra padding) -> 
https://plnkr.co/edit/lebssfByRS7zwWOC4wwJ?p=preview

```
a {
  display:inline-block;
}
```

Comment: In the 1st plunker, the image has a height and width css style of 24, in the second, of 14. I don't think it has anything to do with the anchor, or the display.

Comment: `<a>` is an inline tag in the first place. You've labeled it as a block, which gives it explicit dimensions, in this case `77 x 20` instead of `auto x auto`. The anchor has nothing to do with the image padding - if you make the size of the image equal to both plunkers, there's no difference in the display.

Comment: So yeah it turns out the size is important, not the display. But both of my questions still remain, in that 1) when the image is small enough, why is there the extra couple of pixels below the image in the anchor tag? (if image height is 14px, the anchor tag is 17px) BUT then 2) When the image is large enough they are the same size, but the img tag seems to be shifted upwards?

Comment: To see the second point, with no other styling make the image 17px x 17px, and inspect element. The element is clearly relatively shifted